# Android Chrome shortcuts are grayed out after transfer with "Smart Switch". How come?

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

I recently bought a new phone and tried to transfer all my stuff from the old phone using Samsung's "Smart Switch" (both phones are identical Samsung S9s, Android V10). It basically worked, but all my Chrome shortcuts on the new phone are now grayed out and don't work. When I click on one, I get the message "App version downgraded or isn't compatible with this shortcut". I did a thorough search on SO and Google with no joy.
**Any ideas on what's wrong or how to fix it?**

Notes:

- If I add a *new* shorcut, it works fine.
- I don't want to re-create them all because I have a LOT of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the  Chrome version on my new phone was *older* than the old phone. After many failed attempts, I was able to update Chrome to the latest version from the Play Store. Voila! The shortcuts now work.